# Unzip function shows weird output in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, output, unzip

I currently have a code:

```
Name=$(ls | grep .zip)
pass=$(unzip $Name)
echo $pass
```

when I run it, it gives me:

```
[37366.zip] 5900.zip password: 
password incorrect--reenter: 
password incorrect--reenter: 
   skipping: 5900.zip                incorrect password
Archive: 37366.zip
```

(Notice, the zip is encrypted)
I now want this variable 'pass' to show me the line '[37366.zip] 5900.zip password:' instead of giving back 'Archive: 37366.zip'
What can I write to retrieve this output.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: `Name=(*.zip)` would be so much easier and safer than `Name=$(ls | grep .zip)`.

Comment: I'd look into tcl+expect to manage programs that require interactive input from the user instead of shell.

Comment: Normally, when you capture output from a program (like `unzip`) in a shell script, the output isn't available until after the program finishes -- i.e. after `unzip` has either successfully received a password & decrypted the archive or *not* gotten a password and failed to decrypt it -- meaning that for something like a password prompt it's too late for it to be relevant. What are you trying to accomplish by capturing the password prompt?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm trying to get the result, since I know that the password is the name of the second file (here, 5900). But the challenge is that this zip file contains another zip file and so on. So I want to automate the process and find the last zip file.

Comment: I'd recommend parsing the output of `unzip -l` instead. The format's a bit messy, but it'll be way easier to capture.